# What did the first cat of Arnold's "cat map" look like?

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems, math-history

Arnold's "cat map" is now one of the typical first examples of an Anosov diffeomorphism of the two torus $\mathbb{T}^2$. It is obtained by considering the linear map $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ with matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 1 \\
    1       & 1
\end{bmatrix}

with respect the the standard basis. Since $A$ preserves the integer lattice and has determinant one, it descends to an invertible map $f_A: \mathbb{T}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2$.

I believe I once read that the original cat image was due to Arnold, and that whatever the original source is hard to find in print (I cannot recall a source, so this could be completely wrong.) I have seen a variety of cats used as a substitute. [Here is a possible first cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm7p8.jpg) that I found on Google images. I recall at one point seeing a similar image in an old dynamics text (again, I can't recall the book), which looked similar to think linked image but was not solidly black, it was just an outline.

I would appreciate really appreciate any references or links!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the first cat, but there is one on p. 6 in the 1968 book by Arnold & Avez, *Ergodic Problems of Classical Mechanics*.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I've found a quote from a footnote in Boris Hasselblatt's "Ergodic Theory and Negative Curvature" about this:

Comment: " Since there were typewritten notes by Avez, the existence of which was
pointed out to me by David Chillingworth, that preceded the joint book and included a similar picture that used a bat, physicists should consider the term “Avez bat map.” There is a possibility that a yet earlier paper by Arnold had the cat picture after all, so the safest way to cut the historical knot is to note that this map also [is the square of that map that] gives the recursion for the Fibonacci numbers, and could hence be called the Fibonacci rabbit map..."